# JSのプロパティ入出力時にアクセスメソッドを動かしたい

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptでいろいろコードを試しています。
ES5で考えています。

プロパティの入出力に対して、
アクセスメソッドを動かすことはできますか？

C#などではプロパティに対して
get/setなどのアクセスメソッドを
記述するのが普通ですが、

JavaScriptでは、プロパティという言葉自体が
公開されたフィールド変数、の意味で使われています。

なので、たとえば下記のように書くのですが

この時に、getRight() とよびださなければいけないのですが
かっこわるいというか
他言語からの移植などの場合にも困るので
アクセスメソッドは公開せずに
right プロパティをよみだしたときに
getRigthが裏で動いている、というようなことが
実現できないのか、と思っています。

ご存じの方おられましたら、教えてください。
よろしくおねがいします。

また、ES5は無理そうだとか、
ES6なら or TypeScriptなら、可能なども
おしえていただければ、助かります。

```
var common = {};
(function () {
  var _ = common;

  //Rect(top,left,height,width)
  _.Rect = function (top, left, height, width) {
    if (!(this instanceof common.Rect)) {
      return new common.Rect(top, left, height, width);
    }
    this.top = top;
    this.left = left;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  };
  _.Rect.prototype.getRight = function() {
    return this.left + this.width;
  };
  _.Rect.prototype.getBottom = function() {
    return this.top + this.height;
  };

}());

var rect1 = common.Rect(1,1,1,1);
というように使う
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) でgetを使うことでできると思います。
以下例：

```js
var common = {};
(function () {
  var _ = common;

  //Rect(top,left,height,width)
  _.Rect = function (top, left, height, width) {
    if (!(this instanceof common.Rect)) {
      return new common.Rect(top, left, height, width);
    }
    this.top = top;
    this.left = left;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "right", { get: function () { return this.left + this.width; } });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "bottom", { get: this.getBottom });

  };
  _.Rect.prototype.getRight = function() {
    return this.left + this.width;
  };
  _.Rect.prototype.getBottom = function() {
    return this.top + this.height;
  };

}());

var rect1 = common.Rect(1,2,3,4);
console.log(rect1.right);
console.log(rect1.bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

BLUEPIXYさんに教えていただいた方法を応用して
下記コードで、アクセスメソッドをprivateにすることもでき、
setも作成することができました。

こんなことができると全くしらなかったので、大変勉強になりました。
知らなかったので検索することもできませんでした。

BLUEPIXYさん、ありがとうございます。

```
_.Rect = function (top, left, height, width) {
  if (!(this instanceof common.Rect)) {
    return new common.Rect(top, left, height, width);
  }
  this.top = top;
  this.left = left;
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;

  var getRight = function() {
    return this.left + this.width;
  };
  var setRight = function(value) {
    this.width = value - this.left;
  };
  var getBottom = function() {
    return this.top + this.height;
  };

  Object.defineProperty(this, "right", {
    get: getRight,
    set: setRight
  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, "bottom", {
    get: getBottom 
  });
};
```

※コメント欄では文字数が足りなかったので、
回答として、コードも含めて投稿しておきます。